# What's is the name for the construct $myVar | % { ...... ...... }

Tags: loops, powershell, scripting

All the loop constructs have a name, like "*foreach loop*" or "*do loop*" etc. How should we refer to the following construct:

```
$myVar | % {
    ......
    ......
}
```

Please, do address this query for its i

Comment: What scripting language are you using? Can you add the appropriate tag?

Answer (score 1):

'%' is an alias to the Foreach-Object cmdlet, basically it is a loop but is more of a foreach loop designed for the pipeline. See the [about_Foreach](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847816.aspx) topic for more information.